# Scanning a file and getting two tokens at a time and saving those in an ArrayList

Tags: java, token, polynomials

Hi everyone this is my first question here so I apologize in advance if it is not in the correct format for this forum. I'm a comp sci student and I am really a novice programmer. For an assignment, I need to read in a file of polynomials and then sort them from highest degree to lowest. On each line of the file I have a coefficient and an exponent separated by a space.

This is what my .txt file looks like:
"5.6 3
4 1
8.3 0" which represents the polynomial 5.6x^3 + 4x + 8.3

I have to scan the file from a JFileChooser and then add the tokens to an ArrayList of type Polynomial. My question/problem is how can I run the file contents through a for loop and separate the first token(coefficients) from the second token(exponents) and then add them to the ArrayList? I'm going to need the exponents to be of type int and the coefficients should be double.

This is what I have so far:

ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

```
    // scanner used to read each line
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);

        if (file.isFile()) {
            while (scan.hasNext()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < something.size(); i++) {
                       //this is where I'm lost, not sure what I need to do here
               }
                
            }
        }
      ....
```

Thank you guys I appreciate the assistance.

-Linden

EDIT:

Alright I figured it out, it was a lot more complicated than I thought. Here's what I did:
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

```
        if (file.isFile()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <=2; i ++) {
                term(scan);
            }
        }

static void term(Scanner scan) {
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String [] splitter = s.split(" "); 
    String coefficient = splitter[0];
    String exponent = splitter[1];
    //populating 
    try {
        arrayList.add(new Polynomial(coefficient, exponent));
    } catch (InvalidPolynomialSyntax e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks to the two guys that tried to help me out and the 24 viewers who didn't lol

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to look at the scanner class.  What methods does it have that you should use to get the data you need?

I don't want to give you the answer to your homework out of respect but broadly what you need is a way to get each line of that file from the scanner so you can compare the contents of each line to each other.

So look at the [scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) documentation and see what it has that you can use.

Start by simply trying to print out each line.  Once you do that you can think about how you want to compare them.

Comment: Thank you sir I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

you can read file as one sentence. First get all the text such as `5.6 3 4 1 8.3 0` as string. Then you can just use  `String [] arrayOfNumbers = yourString.split(" ");`
This will split the string according to `" "` character so you get numbers directly.

Comment: Thanks bro! I used it and figured it out :)